# Highcharts, labeling axes, last label not shown correctly, potential bug

Tags: highcharts

In the following example the last label is not shown as expected. There are 12 value pairs and 12 labels. I'd expect the last label to be the specified label, instead the index 12 is shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrizzl/9eN2C/

OR:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<meta charset = 'utf-8'>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='chart1994257d6b2b' class='highcharts'></div>  
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($){
    $(function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            "dom": "chart1994257d6b2b",
            "width":    800,
            "height":    400,
            "yAxis": {"labels": {"enabled": true},"min":0},
            "xAxis": {"categories": [ "KW 1", "KW 2", "KW 3", "KW 4", "KW 5", "KW 6", "KW 7", "KW 8", "KW 9", "KW 10", "KW 11", "KW 12" ],
                "labels": {"overflow": "justify", "enabled": true, 
                    "rotation":    -45, 
                    "y":     20, 
                    "align": "right"
                }, 
                "tickmarkPlacement": "on",
                "tickInterval":      2 
            },
            "series": [{"data": [
                [1,74],[2,60],[3,79],[4,94],[5,90],[6,83],[7,120],[8,90],[9,90],[10,29],[11,70],[12,66 ]],
                "type": "line",
                "name": "Test" 
            }],
            "id": "chart1994257d6b2b",
            "chart": {"renderTo": "chart1994257d6b2b"} 
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category "numbering" is zero based, your series is one based, modify your series indexes:

```
  series": [{"data": [
      [0,74],[1,60],[2,79],[3,94],[4,90],[5,83],[6,120],[7,90],[8,90],[9,29],[10,70],[11,66]
   ],
   "type": "line",
    "name": "Test" 
  }]
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/9eN2C/3/).